# Codemodel: generic types generation in a loop .narrow()?

Tags: java, generics, code-generation, sun-codemodel

I am using sun-codemodel to generate code. I have problem with generics. I know that to generate something like

```
LinkedList<String>,
```

I need to use

```
JType jtype = jCodeModel.ref("LinkedList").narrow(jCodeModel.ref("String"));
```

However, how do I create something more general, for more than one generic type?

```
HashMap<String,Integer>
```

I would like to do it in the loop so that it supports any number of arguments in custom classes, but for the code like:

```
for(String name: names()){
  returnTypeClass = jCodeModel.ref(name).narrow(jCodeModel.ref(name));
}
```

the output is something like this:

```
JNarrowedClass(JCodeModel$JReferencedClass(HashMap)<Integer>)<String>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with CodeModel, but looking at the API documentation it seems there's a varargs overload: [`narrow(JClass...)`](https://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JClass.html#narrow%28com.sun.codemodel.JClass...%29). Presumably this is used for resolving multiple type parameters. So in the case of `HashMap<String, Integer>`, you would do:

```
JType jtype = jCodeModel.ref("HashMap").narrow(
        jCodeModel.ref("String"),
        jCodeModel.ref("Integer")
);
```

And generalizing this to your loop:

```
Collection<JClass> typeArgClasses = new ArrayList<>();
for (String name : names()) {
    typeArgClasses.add(jCodeModel.ref(name));
}
JType jtype = jCodeModel
        .ref(typeName)
        .narrow(typeArgClasses.toArray(new JClass[typeArgClasses.size()]);
```